# questions about a particular string within printf

Tags: c

I found this C language fragment:

```
printf("[%d] %.*s\n", cnt++, temp - field, field);
```

where `temp` and `field` are `char *` and `cnt` is an integer.

But I don't understand the use of `%.*s` in format string within `printf`.

Can-please-any of you help me ?

Comment: For reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html (see the section "*Format of the format string*")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.*` in `printf` to specify that the precision is to be given as an argument. In your case, that argument is `temp - field`, the difference between the two pointers.

Comment: It deserves noting that in the case of printing a string with the `%…s` format, “If a precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written (including shift sequences, if any)” C11 7.21.6.1. In the case of the snippet in the question, the characters at `field` are printed up to `temp` or until `\0` is encountered, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 1):

From some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> `.*`: The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

So, in your case, `field` has the value and `temp-field` its precision.

These percentage-sign symbols, for future reference are called *format specifiers*. (In fact I found the answer to this question by googling just that.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts for this answer,

1. That line is doing pointer arithmetic, a way to calculate the length of a string; based on a convention used in your application perhaps.

   ```
   char *string = "abcdef";  
   char *p1 = string + 3; // def      
   char *p2 = string + 4; // ef    

   printf("%s - %s = %d\n", p1, p2, (int) (p1 - p2));
   ```

   output

   > 0x400709 - 0x40070a = -1

   Note that p2 is a shorter string, but a bigger pointer.
2. `.number` is used to specify the precision of integers or the length of a string.

   ```
   // number precision
   printf("%.2f\n", 100.12345); // 100.12

   char *string = "abcdef";

   // print the first 3 characters only
   printf("%.3s\n", string); // abc

   // print the first X characters
   int dynamicLength = 2;
   printf("%.*s\n", dynamicLength, string); // ab
   ```

   Note that by using `.*` what you are saying is:

   > I won't know the precision until the program is running.

Comment: The example in 1. invokes undefined behavior by subtracting pointers that are not pointing into the same array. C11 6.5.6:9

Comment: You are right, but the gist is the same, the length is being calculated through pointer arithmetic. I just made up my example, as the OP didn't provide a full snippet. I've updated the answer with a more secure example.